# Secure MySQL connection from another server

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a database containing a list of vehicles, of which the first three columns are used to populate chained  option values using AJAX.  These three menus enable selection of a specific vehicle on my website.  I've been asked if this vehicle look-up can be made available on a 3rd party website, with the intention of using the three-tier menu's to return a small, explode-able string as $_POST data on the 3rd party site.

What is the best way to achieve this please?  I can have remote connections enabled but I'm wary of doing so before I know how to protect it sufficiently.

Sorry if this seems dumb! I've not worked with any connections other than localhost as yet.

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any reason to give the third party access to your database.

Since it looks like you are on wanting to give them a fairly small amount of public-accessable data, why not simply have a url on your own site that returns the data in XML or JSON format, which they do whatever they want with.

That solves your immediate requirement and you can develop this into a more complex service if you need it.

---

Here's some simple PHP which you can use to return your data in JSON format.  Replace the SQL with something to suit your database.

```
$sth = mysql_query("select m.make, l.model, i.count from makes m, models l, inventory i where i.makeid = makeid and i.modelid = l.modelid");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

**Important note**: this code is simple but not suitable if you want to accept input from your third party.  If you want to allow them to e.g. query how many Fords you have in stock, you need a prepared statement, for example with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select i.count from makes m, inventory i where i.makeid = makeid and make = :make");    
$stmt->execute(array(':make' => $make));
```

Comment: A good suggestion in that an "API" need not be something overly complex.

Comment: Thanks Colin, this method interests me very much. Not having third party access would be my preferable choice! 

Would you mind expanding on this a little, or perhaps pointing me towards a good resource for achieving this if you're aware of any?

Comment: @user1266648 I have added a couple of examples

Answer (score 3):

I personally would put up an API in front of the database and expose that service, as I am always wary to expose databases to outside parties.

That being said, if the data is not personally identifiable or critical. Then you could certainly let someone access your database.

The best approach would be to create a new user for the third party and give that use only the permissions they need (i.e. only the databases and table they need access to and only the operations (SELECT, UPDATE, etc.) they need)

Another thing to note is that this might also require some change to the my.ini configuration file for MySQL, as standard MySQL installations bind only on localhost.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response.  The table in question has no critically sensitive data but there is critical data contained within other tables of the database, by enabling a remote connection to one table with limited access would I be putting the other tables at risk in any way?

Comment: I would probably pull these tables out into their own database in that case.  But yes, you can restrict the user's ability to only operate on certain tables within a database.

Comment: By opening up those remote connections, even with limited grants you may potentially open yourself up to having other data stolen. If you set up your permissions wrong, they may be able to take that data, OR if there's a mysql exploit it may be possible for them to get around that problem. Putting a layer between the DB and the third party is preferable because even if you set up that database connection properly and allow them only to use a set of stored procedures to access data, you expose yourself to more risk.

Comment: @hsanders I absolutely agree. It would always be preferable to expose an API rather than a database.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it is you have a few options:

1. Make a tunnel between the two servers using something like OpenVPN or an SSH tunnel to allow MySQL remote connections to go through (NEVER EVER LISTEN ON A PUBLIC INTERFACE!). Although, I wouldn't do this for a third party.
2. Create webservices for your interactions between the two servers. If you choose to do this, you should use a known data serialization method like XML or JSON instead of "an explodable string" because that will allow more portability and less code writing to parse your results.